# How to count the number of results in simulation?

Tags: r

How to count the result of the simulation t-test that have rejected?

For example:

```
set.seed(5)
> simulation <- function(n, mu, sigma, mu0, alpha) {
+ rejects <- 0; S <- 100
+ for(i in 1:S) {
+ sample <- rnorm(n, mean=mu, sd=sigma)
+ t.test(sample,mu=mu0)
+ update(rejects)
+ }
+ return(rejects)
+ }
```

In my code rejects is always 0, how can I update(rejects)? If the p-value of t.test < alpha, I want the number of `rejects` +1. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The p value is stored in the p.value parameter of the T test. And to update rejects, you just do `rejects = rejects + 1`.

```
set.seed(5)
simulation <- function(n, mu, sigma, mu0, alpha) {
 rejects <- 0; S <- 100
 for(i in 1:S) {
 sample <- rnorm(n, mean=mu, sd=sigma)
 T=t.test(sample,mu=mu0)
 if (T$p.value < alpha) rejects = rejects+1
 }
 return(rejects)
 }
```